# Modify row style as it gets created

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview which gets populated via a DataTable which is read from a text file.

One of the columns is called "Validated" and it has values such as "Y" or "N".

I would like to change the row colour based on that Y or N value.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
    string cellValue = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Validated"].Value.ToString();
    if (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Validated"].Value != null)
      if (cellValue.Equals("Y") || cellValue.Equals("y"))
      {
        DataGridViewCellStyle style = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
        style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray;
        dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle = style;
      }
    }
  catch { }
}
```

Is there another event that I must use? The one above keeps saying column "Validated" does not exist.

Comment: Avoid empty exceptions like that.

Comment: I know, I am only using it to test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your code logic within `dataGridView1_CellFormatting` event.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Validated"].Value.ToString() == "Y")
            {
                DataGridViewCellStyle style = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
                style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray;
                dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle = style;
            }
}
```

Comment: Yes this works, except one thing. If I have lower "y" in the box it colours in all the rows with N. I've tried ToUpper and same thing. I've updated the code in the question above.

Comment: @sd_dracula Without checking both characters you can use `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` `if (cellValue.Equals("Y", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))`

Comment: I have tried your suggestion above but every single row gets coloured in still. The issue seems to be if the first row is Y then it applies that style to everything else even though it does not enter the IF loop. Any idea why that is?

Answer (score 0):

Is the column's `DataPropertyName` value called "Validated"?  The name of the column doesn't necessarily reference the column in the collection.

Comment: Yes it is called Validated.